# Angular Material 2 Data Table: Capture Property In Template?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm exploring the new data table with the master/detail setup.  I can populate the data from Firebase but I'm trying to use a button click in one of the columns to show an edit form in another view or modal window.  The button below works fine but I'm having trouble capturing the db $key in the event param.  OOP techniques don't seem to work.  I've tried member.$key and row.$key.  The key is displayed in the second column below so it is living on the template.  I don't have this DataSource observable in the template figured out yet.  Ideas???

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="edit">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Edit </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> <button class="badge"
            (click)="goToDetailPage(member.$key)">Edit</button> </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- key Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="key">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Key </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.$key}} </md-cell> // This displays the db key.
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a simple solution.  The issue is I didn't understand this row data thing in AM2 Data Table.  My head is still in the traditional object.property mode.

This is how master - detail can work with  AM2 Data Table. Take the template variable from the second column below and insert it as the click param. It passes the key to whatever function you want such as:

```
goToDetailPage(selectedMemberKey) {
    console.log('selectedMember: ', selectedMemberKey);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/membersAdmin/editMember', selectedMemberKey]);
  };

deleteMember(selectedMemberKey) {
      // Call the confirm dialog component
      this.confirmService
          .confirm('Confirm Delete', 'This action is final. Gone forever!')
          // .do();
          .do(res => {if (res === true) {
              this.membersAdminService.deleteMember(selectedMemberKey);
          }})
          .subscribe(res => this.result = res, err => err);
  }
```

For the html template:

```
      <!-- Delete / Edit Buttons Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="delete">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Delete / Edit </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
      <button (click)="deleteMember(row.$key)">Delete</button>
      <button (click)="goToDetailPage(row.$key)">Edit</button>
    </md-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can't you just pass `row` into `goToDetailPage(row)`? I believe you wouldn't need your Key column

Comment: Leo Caseiro, we need the key to access the Firebase database in the URL string: .../editMember/-Koirn5PbcbPbfHRbaWv.  I don't see how just the row data, the name, skills title, etc, could be used to bring the data from the db to the edit form.  There would have to be a db property search that the Firebase api doesn't seem to have at this time.  However, I start working on such a search soon so maybe I'll figure out how.  We can search by a name property on the client side though.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, if you pass the row, you should be able to access `row.$key` inside your method.

Comment: @LeoCaseiro Thanks! Jeez, it is in my method and works just fine!  I had fixed that and forgot to update this post.  So I'm removing those artifacts from this post and my reference to it and adding what is in my current code. Good catch!  I still had that key column though so nice to clean that out of my template.